# Applying for schengen Visa with a new passport: old passport has US F1 visa without name change

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, f1-visas, slovenia

I am going to change the name on my Indian passport from Given Name:ABC XYZ, Surname: "Blank" ----> Given Name:ABC, Surname: XYZ. My US F1 student visa will remain on my old passport with the old name. As far as I've read, this should not cause issues while re-entering the USA as I will have proof of the name change.

The question I have is regarding an application for Schengen Visa (at the Slovenian embassy in the US): will they accept my US F1 visa with the old name as a proof of stay in the United States? Will having these two passports cause problems for getting the Schengen visa?

Comment: People change their names quite a bit. You have proof of the name change. You have proof that the identity of the person is the same. You should not have a problem.

Comment: @sid This may be an obvious question, but is the name change essential while your visa application is in course?

Comment: @Traveller yes the name change will solve many problems I am having in the US due to the "lack" of a last name. It is important that I get it done asap. Meanwhile, I don't want it to stop my travel around the world :-)